# Трансформация точек фигуры

Tags: графика, матрицы

Есть некая фигура. Допустим, прямоугольник. У него 4 точки.

Есть матрица (2d). По которой нужно трансформировать фигуру.

Задача: найти новые координаты каждой точки.

P.S. Спасибо за понимание, я вообще не студент. И ответ мне нужен не для того, чтобы ответить, а реально на практике. Решение вообще есть, но получается фигня. Вот и хотел посмотреть, что предложат и сравнить со своим...
Спасибо большое, пользователи Хэшкода.

Comment: Есть некий курс. Допустим, "Линейная алгебра".
Есть параграф "Аффинные преобразования", в котором описываются повороты, сжатия и прочие трансормации.
Задача: скачать учебник, почитать параграф, понять.

Comment: @DreamChild Хочется видеть на ХешКоде хорошие вопросы и красивые ответы, а не исповеди студентов-двоечников, которые они пишут с телефона, пока отвлекся препод, принимающий зачет.

Comment: Замечательная серия постов о линейной алгебре, естественно, далеко не все здесь вам нужно, но мне, в свое время, довольно сильно помогли.

http://blog.wolfire.com/2009/07/linear-algebra-for-game-developers-part-1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Афинное преобразование.](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Аффинное_преобразование)

Вам остается только написать несложный скрипт перемножения матриц.